# Is the fundamental mode the only mode produced in free vibration?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, acoustics, vibrations

Let’s say I strike a 2D circular plate with some impulse. Is the fundamental mode the mode that’s always being produced, or is it possible to sustain only higher modes such as a (1,1) mode etc. 
Let’s also say that the 2D circular plate is being damped, if we only observe the fundamental mode, is it because higher energy modes get damped out more quickly?

Usually one is able to solve for the fundamental frequency using the flexural rigidity and density in a fourth order PDE, but does its solutions tell you anything about which mode is preferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can excite any mode by hitting a drum. If you could only ever excite the fundamental, then every drum should sound exactly like a pure sine wave, which is very far from realistic.

There are a few factors that control the distribution of energy in the harmonics.

- Where you hit the drum. A mode with a node at the point you hit the drum is sure to not be excited; a mode with an antinode will be maximally excited. More formally, you can compute this by taking the inner product between the mode's amplitude profile and the impulse.
- Decay of harmonics. Assuming standard linear damping, all modes decay exponentially, but higher harmonics decay much more quickly.
- How you hit the drum. Some mallets remain in contact with the drum for a significant time $T$, where $T$ is on the order of milliseconds. That means that harmonics with period $\leq T$ are suppressed.

Comment: However, what if it weren’t a drum. Let’s say it were a coin (circular plate with an open boundary condition), will anything change qualitatively?

Comment: @RussellYang The three points I made here all still hold, though I imagine the details would change a bit. For example, the frequencies for a coin would all be much higher.